# Смена содержимого блока текста при нажатии по ссылке

Tags: javascript

Есть два ссылки.

При нажатии на первую ссылку, выводится "Отображаемый блок 1". При клике на вторую, выводится "Отображаемый блок 2", но "Отображаемый блок 1" не исчезает.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы div блоки сменяли друг друга?

```
<a href="#" onclick="openbox('box1'); return false">Записаться</a>
<a href="#" onclick="openbox('box2'); return false">Записаться</a>

<div id="box1" style="display: none;">Отображаемый блок 1</div>
<div id="box2" style="display: none;">Отображаемый блок 2</div>

function openbox(id){
    display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;

    if(display=='none'){
       document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
    }else{
       document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Вот результат выполнения скрипта: https://jsfiddle.net/960qmq9p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пометьте div-ы с текстом специальным классом.

```js
function openbox(id) {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll(".block-of-text");
  for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    if (all[i].id == id) {
      all[i].style.display = (all[i].style.display == 'none')? 'block' : 'none';
    } else {
      all[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="openbox('box1'); return false">Записаться</a>
<a href="#" onclick="openbox('box2'); return false">Записаться</a>

<div class="block-of-text" id="box1" style="display: none;">Отображаемый блок 1</div>
<div class="block-of-text" id="box2" style="display: none;">Отображаемый блок 2</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Все отлично работает!

Comment: @FlapJack Пожалуйста. Успехов!