# Как в js при клике на один объект скрывать все остальные по id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтоб при кликаньи на один объект - все другие закрывались?
Верстка:

```
<div class="item"><span><a href="#" onclick="openbox('favorite_box'); return false"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span></div>
<div class="item"><span><a href="#" onclick="openbox('share_box'); return false"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span></div>
<div class="item"><span><a href="#" onclick="openbox('hour_box'); return false"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span></div>
<div class="item"><span><a href="#" onclick="openbox('phone_box'); return false"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span></div>


    <div id="favorite_box"  style="display: none;">  Favorite   </div>
    <div id="share_box"     style="display: none;">  Share Box  </div>
    <div id="hour_box"      style="display: none;">  Hour Box   </div>
    <div id="phone_box"     style="display: none;">  Phone      </div>
```

script:

```
function openbox(id){
    display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;

       if(display=='none'){
          document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
          }else{
          document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
       }
}
```

Comment: в Вашем html нет атрибутов `id`

Comment: и еще, как ты собираешься потом на другие кликать, если задаешь им display:none????

Comment: @Air вероятно, это `id` элементов, которые не показаны в вопросе

Comment: Подождите, я уже это видел, и даже с `openbox`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739480. Атака клоунов?

Comment: @Igor, скорее всего...

Comment: Вероятно, нет. Автор мог скопировать исходный код там и получить новые проблемы... Или первого уволили, а скрипт с задачей достался вновь нанятому сотруднику)

Comment: народ, боюсь даже не дубликат, а точная  копия...  сранна, что автор молчит....

Comment: вообще, этот вопрос от 2012г. есть на javascript.ru... И ещё от 2010г. на другом ресурсе))

Comment: я делал правку кода, не скопировал вовремя, прошу прощения. Нет, код сам писал, инфу возможно из одного источника с автором подобного вопроса брали, что названия, как вы говорите, одинаковые.сейчас посмотрю, спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

var div = document.querySelectorAll('div:not(.item)');

function openbox(id){
    hideOtherDiv(id)
    var display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;

    if (display === 'none'){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
    }
}

function hideOtherDiv(id) {
    Array.prototype.filter.call(div, function(elm) {
        if (elm.id !== id) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }).forEach(function(elm) {
        elm.style.display='none';
    });
}
```